# How to make a program keep asking user to enter Value in C programming

Tags: c

I know that I have to use the while loop, however I did try to put the while condition as while(choice =! 'e') {program statement} v....v but it doesn't work. I just new in C and this is my 1st Assignment, My code works as normal but I just want to make it perfect like a real ATM machine. So basically the assignment asked student to create a ATM machine v...v So what I want is after the user go through 1 of 5 selection, the program will ask them like at the beginning to to other transaction until they press 'Exit' option as 'e'.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Could you explain why it does not work as it is?

Comment: everything is working fine, but I want it to be more real. Like when you go to the ATM machine, after you finish your transaction, it will prompt out the menu so you could do other transaction, but my it doesn't, it like normal code just end by return to (0). So I want it stop when user press exit, not like stop when finish transaction

Comment: that is what loops are for, as per some of the suggested answers...

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should use a `do...while` loop.

**Why?**

Because it would give you a chance to initialize your control variable (`account`) before testing it for valid values.

Your code would become this (I'm skipping some unrelated code):

```
int ChooseAccountType(int cheq, int sav)
{
    int account = 0;
    do {
        printf("Please Select Account\n");
        printf("*    1.Chequing     *\n");
        printf("*    2.Saving       *\n");
        printf("*********************\n");
        scanf("%d",&account);
    } while ( account != 1 || account != 2 );
    if ( account == 1 )
        return cheq;
    else if ( account == 2 )
        return sav;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find it somewhat interesting that your reasoning for using a `do..while` loop is so you can "initialize your control variable (account)", but your sample code fails to initialize the account variable. :-)

Comment: I think It should be while as a condition check at the beginning otherwise it will check at the end ( I do it as a EOF for while so I know she should check at the beginning )

Comment: @KenWhite Indeed... it is late night here... guess I'm a sleep walker now!

Comment: @user3739485 Yes, it will check at the end, after the input has been read.

Comment: This is the think I want to repeat
    printf(" INSERT YOUR ATM CARD : ");
    printf("\n ***********************************");
    printf("\n *           MENU                  *");
    printf("\n *     a. Deposit                  *");
    printf("\n *     b. Withdraw                 *");
    printf("\n *     c. Interest                 *");
    printf("\n *     d. Check Account Balance    *");
    printf("\n *     e. Exit                     *");
    printf("\n ***********************************");
    printf("\n\n");
S:
    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

Comment: @user3739485 That is why the code is inside the curly braces. Everything inside it will be executed at last once because the check of the control variable is performed after the first execution, not before like a `while` loop.

Comment: @user3739485 Hummmmmmmm.... now I understand. It is very straight forward porting the code I've posted to the one you actually want. Give it a try, and if you can come up with it, I'll update my post with the right answer.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: I tried to put a do while loop in,now the function keep asking to enter until I enter 'e'=exit. However If I enter a or b to do other stuff it doesn't work, just printing out the menu again ?

Answer (score 2):

You say you tried:

```
while (choice =! 'e')
```

The trouble with that is that it *is* valid C, but it is *not* what you intended, which was:

```
while (choice != 'e')
```

As it stands, your loop assigned the value of `!'e'` (which is 0) to `choice`, and then test whether zero is not zero...and it isn't, so the loop is never entered.  The way I wrote it doesn't modify `choice` and does compare to see if it is the same as `'e'`.

Comment: Thanks for correct me that :D 
It's working now but not what I meant. So it only repeat the step of "1.Chequing or 2.Saving" It not repeating the main menu, the one with option for you to choose deposit or withdraw v...v

Comment: One thing I notice is that you use `scanf("%c", &choice);`.  Two things: (1) you should check the return status every time you use `scanf()`, making sure you get the expected number of values converted (so you should compare `if (scanf(...) == 1)` here), and (2) you should probably use `" %c"` to skip newlines etc.  That might be enough to explain your problem.

Comment: I did use %c for choice ? Sorry I get lost in what you're saying. This program has too many parts so I don't understand which part are you talking about. I'm just new in C

Comment: Yes, you used `%c`, but there is a crucial difference between `"%c"` and `" %c"`, where there is a space before the `%` in the second.  That space means 'read zero or more white space characters', and in this context is quite important.

Answer (score 1):

Put your whole program inside a while loop have a reality of a ATM machine

```
while(1){ \\your program }
```

for your menu create a separate function and use it inside a switch statement

**normally when you know all the choices in advance** it is more
convenient to use a **switch** instead of a if-else-if

```
char menu(){
     printf(" INSERT YOUR ATM CARD : ");
     printf("\n ***********************************");
     printf("\n *           MENU                  *");
     printf("\n *     a. Deposit                  *");
     printf("\n *     b. Withdraw                 *");
     printf("\n *     c. Interest                 *");
     printf("\n *     d. Check Account Balance    *");
     printf("\n *     e. Exit                     *");
     printf("\n ***********************************");
     printf("\n\n");
     printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
     scanf("%c", &choice);
     return c;
 }
```

Then your program would be like

```
int main(){

    while (1)
    {
           switch(menu){
             //check for cases
              case 'x':
              case 'X':
                     //do relevant
                     break;
              ...............
              ..............
              case 'e':
              case 'E':
                     //EXIT the program ( not loop )
                     break;

              default:       
                  printf( "Invalid Input! please try again \n" );
                  break; //not necessary 
           }//end switch

    }//end while(super loop-from Embedded systems knowledge Atm machine is a one such)
}//end main
```

Comment: If you want to know about how a switch works in case you don't, follow the link -- 
[switch](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a typo, but the "not equal" operator is !=

You wrote

```
while(choice =! 'e')
```

instead of

```
while(choice != 'e')
```

In the 1st case, you are negating(!) 'e' (what results in 0), and then assigning(=) the result to choice.
I recommend you to enable all compiler warnings to detect these situations.